# How can I configure Swashbuckle to hide curl command and responses table?

Tags: swashbuckle

In SwashbuckleUI my CURL command can get quite big. If I am interested in curl I usually just want to copy it.

Is there a way to configure SwashbuckleUI to

1. hide curl command
2. hide RESPONSES table that shows status code and example return

I could just use stylebot, but I want to explore OOB solutions first.

Asp.Net Core 7

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default expand state for all snippets to `false`.

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
  options.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("requestSnippets", new { defaultExpanded = false });
  options.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("requestSnippetsEnabled", true);
});
```

Another option would be to hide the `div` with a style.
This is not the best solution, but it works. Of course only until Swashbuckle changes its HTML code.

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
  options.HeadContent = "<style>.curl-command {display:none}</style>";
});
```

Tested with `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` `6.5.0`